# expl3 function for fixed number of expansion steps

Tags: expansion, expl3

In expl3, say we want to assign a value to a token list variable `\l_foo_tl` while expanding the value a certain number of times. For a single expansion the easiest way is

```
\tl_set:No \l_foo_tl { ... }
```

For more expansions we can use

```
\exp_args:NNo \tl_set:No \l_foo_tl { ... }
\exp_args:NNNo \exp_args:NNo \tl_set:No \l_foo_tl { ... }
```

and so on. This doesn't scale nicely, though. For four expansions we already have to use `\exp_args_generate:n` to generate proper expansion functions.

Does expl3 provide a generic, expandable function that, once tiggered by a single expansion step, expands its argument a given number of times exactly? If not, what is the most idiomatic way of doing such an expansion series in expl3?

Comment: There isn't anything for an specific number of expansions, but most likely an `f` expansion does what you want here. The `f` expansion will expand the head of the token list (as will `o`) until the the head of the token list is an unexpandable token.

Comment: `f` expands too far in most of the cases. I'm debugging function definitions and actually want to get the results after a certain number of expansion steps.

Comment: See also: [macros - Can one define a '\superexpandafter{n}' that would expand to 2^n-1 '\expandafter's?' - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/can-one-define-a-superexpandaftern-that-would-expand-to-2n-1-expandafter?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Have anyone mentioned the `multiexpand` package? https://ctan.org/pkg/multiexpand

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is now!

<sub>The LaTeX3 people will flay alive me when they see this :|</sub>

Here's an `s`-type expansion (`s` stands for “blame **s**iracusa” for this ;-) that, unlike other expansion flavours, takes an argument. The argument is the number of expansions of `o`-type expansions of the token list. You need then to define your own `\exp_args:N...` commands  that do the expansion of the argument. For example, to expand the first argument four times you can define:

```
\cs_new:Npn \exp_args:Niv { \::s {4} \::: }
```

or to `f`-expand the first, and expand the second two times:

```
\cs_new:Npn \exp_args:Nft { \::f \::s {2} \::: }
```

or the contrary (first→twice, second→`f`):

```
\cs_new:Npn \exp_args:Ntf { \::s {2} \::f \::: }
```

or yet expand some argument an arbitrary amount of times:

```
\cs_new:Npn \exp_times:nNs #1 { \::s {#1} \::: }
```

and so on. Here's the code and some proofs-of-functionality. I define a macro `\a` which expands to `\b`, `\b` to `\c`, and so on until `\f` expands to `g` (to count expansions easily):

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \::s #1#2 \::: #3#4
  {
    \if_int_compare:w #1 > 0 ~
      \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
      \exp_after:wN \__siracusa_exp_step_s:nnnn
    \else:
      \exp_after:wN \__siracusa_exp_end_s:Nnnnn
    \fi:
    \exp_after:wN {#4} {#1} {#2} {#3}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__siracusa_exp_step_s:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \exp_after:wN \::s \exp_after:wN
      { \int_value:w \__int_eval:w #2-1 \__int_eval_end: } {#3} \::: {#4} {#1}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__siracusa_exp_end_s:Nnnnn #1#2#3#4#5
  { \__exp_arg_next:nnn {#2} {#4} {#5} }

% Examples
\cs_new:Npn \exp_times:nNs #1 { \::s {#1} \::: }
\cs_new:Npn \exp_times:nNnfso #1 { \::n \::f \::s {#1} \::o \::: }
\cs_new:Npn \weird_command:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
  { \tl_to_str:n {#1|#2|#3|#4} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\a{\b}
\def\b{\c}
\def\c{\d}
\def\d{\e}
\def\e{\f}
\def\f{g}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_times:nNs {0} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {1} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {2} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {3} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {4} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {5} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {6} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par

\exp_times:nNnfso {0} \weird_command:nnnn{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}\par
\exp_times:nNnfso {1} \weird_command:nnnn{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}\par
\exp_times:nNnfso {2} \weird_command:nnnn{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}\par
\exp_times:nNnfso {3} \weird_command:nnnn{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}\par
\exp_times:nNnfso {4} \weird_command:nnnn{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}\par
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's fantastic! I like how easily those argument types are composable by using the various `\::` functions. So can I take it we'll see `\::s` in the next expl3 release, as you are going to secretly add it to the repo while the rest of the team is asleep? ;)

Comment: @siracusa we never sleep

Comment: @siracusa I doubt this would be useful for more than academic purposes. For everything else there is the `f` expansion. Of course, if you provide an use case, a feature request could be added. It would be fun, though, if I did that ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle [“The empire on which the sun never sets”](https://what-if.xkcd.com/48/) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I can offer an expandable mechanism `\Expandtimes` which processes an argument which is to hold an ⟨integer expression⟩ whose evaluation-result is to be a value which denotes how many times an expansion-step is to be triggered to the first token of subsequent stuff.
`\Expandtimes{⟨integer expression⟩}` checks whether the ⟨integer expression⟩ evaluates to 0.
If so, expansion is done.
If not so, a loop `\__udiez_exp_IntersperseWithExpafterwNLoop:nn` is started on the tokens representing the value of the ⟨integer expression⟩ decremented by 1:
These tokens are accumulated one by one with `\exp_after:wN` prepended to each of them.  Then `\exp_after:wN\Expandtimes\exp_after:wN{` is prepended and `\exp_after:wN}` is appended.
This way the call for the next iteration is constructed where ⟨integer expression⟩ is decremented and you have an `\exp_after:wN`-chain which triggers one expansion step on the first token of the stuff right behind `\Expandtimes`' ⟨integer expression⟩-argument.

This way the tokens where expansion shall be applied to do not need to be grabbed as an argument in each iteration.

```latex
%\errorcontextlines=10000
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \exp:w \Expandtimes{<integer expression evaluating to value K>}<tokens>
%%     or -- as long as expl3 defines \exp:w equal to \romannumeral --
%% \romannumeral\Expandtimes{<integer expression evaluating to value K>}<tokens>
%%
%%  ->   <tokens> is hit K times by \expandafter/\exp_after:wN .
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \Expandtimes #1
  { \int_compare:nNnTF { #1 }{>}{0}
                       { \exp_args:No \__udiez_exp_IntersperseWithExpafterwNLoop:nn {\int_value:w \int_eval:n{ #1-1 }}{} }
                       { \exp_end: }
  }
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \__udiez_exp_IntersperseWithExpafterwNLoop:nn #1#2 
  {  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 }
                      { \exp_after:wN \Expandtimes \exp_after:wN {#2\exp_after:wN} }
                      { \exp_args:No \__udiez_exp_movehead:nnn {\tl_head:w #1{} \q_stop}{#1}{#2} }  
  }
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \__udiez_exp_movehead:nnn #1#2#3 
  {  \exp_args:No \__udiez_exp_IntersperseWithExpafterwNLoop:nn {\use_i:nn{}#2}{#3\exp_after:wN#1}  }
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Argument-type based on \Expandtimes :
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\cs_new:Npn \::s #1#2 \::: #3#4
  {  \exp_args:No \__exp_arg_next:nnn {\exp:w \Expandtimes{#1}#4}{#2}{#3}  }
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Examples
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\cs_new:Npn \exp_times:nNs #1 { \::s {#1} \::: }
\cs_new:Npn \exp_times:nNnfso #1 { \::n \::f \::s {#1} \::o \::: }
\cs_new:Npn \weird_command:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
  { \tl_to_str:n {#1|#2|#3|#4} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\a{\b}
\def\b{\c}
\def\c{\d}
\def\d{\e}
\def\e{\f}
\def\f{g}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_times:nNs {0} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {1} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {2} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {3} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {4} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {5} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par
\exp_times:nNs {6} \tl_to_str:n { \a }\par

\exp_times:nNnfso {0} \weird_command:nnnn{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}\par
\exp_times:nNnfso {1} \weird_command:nnnn{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}\par
\exp_times:nNnfso {2} \weird_command:nnnn{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}\par
\exp_times:nNnfso {3} \weird_command:nnnn{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}\par
\exp_times:nNnfso {4} \weird_command:nnnn{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}\par
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as with the code of [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492956):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before remembering about the post above, I could not figure out the argument  swap trick and implement something like this for [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618428/250119).
(warning: inappropriate namespacing! `um` is Unicode-math's namespace)

```
% Function `\__um_do_exp_after_<X in roman>:`
% absorb 2 tokens, expand the second token (absorbing later tokens in the process if required) X times
% without expanding to 2^X-1 \expandafter

% base case (1 time)
\cs_new_eq:NN \__um_do_exp_after_i: \exp_after:wN

% helper function
% define <#2> to expandafter 1 time + do <#1>.
% #1 should be __um_do_exp_after_ <X-1> : and #2 should be __um_do_exp_after_ <X> :
\cs_set:Nn \__um_exp_after_aux:NN {
  \cs_new:Npn #2 {
    \exp_after:wN #1 \exp_after:wN
  }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__um_exp_after_aux:NN {cc}

% induction case. define up to \__um_do_exp_after_x: = 10 expansions
\int_step_inline:nnn {2} {10} {
  \__um_exp_after_aux:cc {__um_do_exp_after_ \int_to_roman:n {#1-1} :} {__um_do_exp_after_ \int_to_roman:n {#1} :}
}
```

As you can tell, this snippet

- defines `\__um_do_exp_after_i:` = `\exp_after:wN` such that `\__um_do_expand_after_i: <token1> <token2>` expands `token2` once.
- defines `\__um_do_exp_after_ii:` = `\exp_after:wN \__um_do_exp_after_i: \exp_after:wN` such that `\__um_do_expand_after_ii: <token1> <token2>` expands `token2` twice.
- defines `\__um_do_exp_after_iii:` = `\exp_after:wN \__um_do_exp_after_ii: \exp_after:wN` such that `\__um_do_expand_after_iii: <token1> <token2>` expands `token2` three times.
- etc.

I didn't measure the difference, but I "feel" that this could be faster because it doesn't need to do the integer arithmetic.

---

Some note regarding the "swap trick" in the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492956/250119):

- Note that if you want to expand the second argument in `\myfunction {argument 1} {argument 2}` directly using `\expandafter`, it's very hard because you have to put `\expandafter` before
  each token in `argument 1` which can have an arbitrary number of tokens.
- So the basic idea is to make some function to swap the desired argument to the first one, use `\expandafter` as usual, then swap back.

  ```
      \myfunction {argument 1} {argument 2}
  →   \expandafter \myfunctionaux \expandafter {argument 2} {argument 1}
  →   \myfunctionaux {argument 2 expanded once} {argument 1}
  →   \myfunctionauxi {argument 1} {argument 2 expanded once}
  ```

See also:  [pstricks - How do I have to invoke \expandafter for a macro with multiple arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133768/250119).