# Test if a pgfkey is empty in a safe way

Tags: tex-core, pgfkeys

I have this little example to check if a key is empty:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter

\newcount\cnt\cnt=0\relax
\tikzset{dir/.is family}
\tikzset{dir/t0/.initial={}}

\begin{document}

% \tikzset{dir/t0={\small SMALL}}

Key \the\cnt is: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dir/t\the\cnt}

\edef\mykey{x\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dir/t\the\cnt}}
\edef\plainx{x}
\ifx\plainx\mykey
    key t\the\cnt{} is empty
\else
    key t\the\cnt{} is not empty
\fi

\end{document}
```

and it works unless I put a font-changing command in the key itself (uncomment the `tikzset`):

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@setfontsize #1#2#3->\@nomath #1
                                 \ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \let \@curr...
l.18 ...ykey{x\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dir/t\the\cnt}
                                                  }
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How can I check if the key is set to `{}` in a safe way? I need to do that using core packages, the code must be LaTeX and ConTeXt compatible...

Comment: `\protected@edef` instead of `\edef` should work...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik yes, it works... if you write it in an answer I'll happily accept it! Is `\protected@edef` available in ConTeXt?

Comment: Loading all of `tikz` to only use `pgfkeys` is a bit inefficient.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes ;-) but this was a minimal example stripped down from the innards of `circuitikz`...

Comment: Question solved?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner yes! Sorry, I forgot to mark it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font change commands are (now) robust, so if you use `\protected@edef` instead of plain `\edef`, then LaTeX's protection mechanism will kick in and prevent the expanson of `\small`. However this will only work if the key contains robust or expandable commands (which is most often not the case).

A more robust way of doing this exploits the implementation details of `\pgfkeysvalueof`, which is just `\csname pgfk@<full path to key>\endcsname` (after one expansion). The `\csname` expands whatever is in the path and makes a control sequence (after a second expansion), then one more expansion (third) yields the contents of the key, so you can use:

```latex
\def\unexpandedvalueof#1{%
  \unexpanded
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\pgfkeysvalueof{#1}}}
```

to expand `\pgfkeysvalueof` exactly 3 times and leave the result inside `\unexpanded`, so it doesn't expand further in `\edef`.

Note that, since `\pgfkeysvalueof` uses directly `\csname`, in case the key didn't exist previously, TeX will leave `\relax` after the expansion and the emptiness test will result false. If you want it to return true for an undefined key, then you need to check for the `\relax` before expanding the actual control sequence that stores the key:

```latex
\def\unexpandedvalueof#1{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\rmano@valueof@chk\pgfkeysvalueof{#1}}
\def\rmano@valueof@chk#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {{}}%
    {\expandafter{#1}}}
```

Here's a compilable example:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{unravel}
\makeatletter

\newcount\cnt\cnt=0\relax
\tikzset{dir/.is family}
\tikzset{dir/t0/.initial={}}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{dir/t0={\small SMALL}}

Key \the\cnt is: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dir/t\the\cnt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\unexpandedvalueof[1]{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\rmano@valueof@chk\pgfkeysvalueof{#1}}
\def\rmano@valueof@chk#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {{}}% #1 is \relax, so consider empty
    {\expandafter{#1}}}% otherwise, leave the key after one more expansion
\makeatletter

\edef\mykey{x\unexpandedvalueof{/tikz/dir/t\the\cnt}}
\edef\plainx{x}
\ifx\plainx\mykey
    key t\the\cnt{} is empty
\else
    key t\the\cnt{} is not empty
\fi

\edef\mykey{x\unexpandedvalueof{/tikz/dir/tBOO}}
\edef\plainx{x}
\ifx\plainx\mykey
    key t\the\cnt{} is empty
\else
    key t\the\cnt{} is not empty
\fi

\end{document}
```

---

ConTeXt renames the `\unexpanded` primitive, so you need to use `\normalunexpanded` instead. You can use this code to define a generic `\pgfutil@unexpanded`:

```
\ifcsname normalunexpanded\endcsname
  \let\pgfutil@unexpanded\normalunexpanded
\else
  \let\pgfutil@unexpanded\unexpanded
\fi
```

Comment: Thanks! this is a couple (4!) of `\expandafter` over my skills...

Comment: ...and I think that using `\def` instead of `\newcommand` makes it ConTeXt-compatible. Will check anyway

Comment: @Rmano The rule is `2^n-1` `\expandafter`, where `n` is the number of expansions you want. Or you can use `expl3` and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492956/134574) to give the exact number of expansions ;-) To make it work in ConTeXt you'd need to define `\long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}` and `\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}` as well (edit: or use the `pgfutil` versions; I'll edit my answer)

Comment: @Rmano ConTeXt renames some primitives, including `\unexpanded`, so you need to check for that. I added a conditional which defines `\pgfutil@unexpanded` regardless of format (it works at least in ConTeXt, Plain, and LaTeX). That and `\pgfutil@firstoftwo` and `\pgfutil@secondoftwo` should be enough to make that code format-agnostic :-)